# Calculate average depending on number of instances on each line - Bash - AWK

Tags: bash, awk, average

How can you work out the average on each line when each row has a variation on the number of alphanumeric instances including a final total average?

ie. pie.txt:

```
0.8pie 0.7pie 0.6pie            
34.2pie 34.1pie 35.8pie 
42pie 43pie 43pie
44pie 41pie 38pie
0.8pie
34.2pie 34.1pie
42pie 43pie 43.0pie
44.1pie 41pie 38.7pie 58.2pie
```

Desired Output:

```
Instances of Pie:               Avg:
0.8pie 0.7pie 0.6pie            Avg pie:  0.7pie
34.2pie 34.1pie 35.8pie         Avg pie:  34.7pie
42pie 43pie 43pie               Avg pie:  42.7pie
44pie 41pie 38pie               Avg pie:  41pie
0.8pie                          Avg pie:  0.8pie
34.2pie 34.1pie                 Avg pie:  34.15pie
42pie 43pie 43.0pie             Avg pie:  42.7pie
44.1pie 41pie 38.7pie 58.2pie   Avg pie:  45.5pie

Total Average:                            30.28pie
```

If there was always a set amount on each line like 2 or lets say 3 pies then yeah I can easily utilise `awk print ($1+$2+$3)/3` etc. But I'm struggling when there is a variance on each line.

I would imagine the use of conditional statements to determine the number on each line.
ie. If row one has 3 then divide by 3, if row two has 4 then divide by 4 etc.

Can anyone kindly assist?

Comment: What have you tried? What research did you do? `kindly assist?` I would remove all the `pie` from input (in sed or awk). Then in awk, I would iterate foreach field in awk, calculate sum, and divide by NF. Looks like a very, very short awk script.

Comment: @KamilCuk no need to remove `pie`, in numerical context that will get discarded

Comment: @Sundeep: sorry. I didn't see that my proposal calculated the average of an entire file, I've removed the URL.

Comment: Note that the average of the averages (30.27) is different from the average of all the pies (33.47)

Comment: @glennjackman what would you change or I guess append on anubhava's code to output the average of all the pies as well?

Comment: That should not be very hard to figure out. Give it a try and ask questions if it's not working for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'function prt(s1, s2) {printf "%-40s %s\n", s1, s2} NR==1 {prt("Instances of Pie:", "Avg:")} NF {s=0; for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) s+=$i; avg=s/NF; ++rec; sum+=avg; prt($0, "Avg pie:  " avg "pie")} !NF; END {prt("\nTotal Average:", sum/rec "pie")}' file

Instances of Pie:                        Avg:
0.8pie 0.7pie 0.6pie                     Avg pie:  0.7pie
34.2pie 34.1pie 35.8pie                  Avg pie:  34.7pie
42pie 43pie 43pie                        Avg pie:  42.6667pie
44pie 41pie 38pie                        Avg pie:  41pie
0.8pie                                   Avg pie:  0.8pie
34.2pie 34.1pie                          Avg pie:  34.15pie
42pie 43pie 43.0pie                      Avg pie:  42.6667pie
44.1pie 41pie 38.7pie 58.2pie            Avg pie:  45.5pie

Total Average:                           30.2729pie
```

A more readable form:

```sh
awk '
function prt(s1, s2) {
   printf "%-40s %s\n", s1, s2
}
NR == 1 {
   prt("Instances of Pie:", "Avg:")
}
NF {
   s = 0
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
      s += $i
   avg = s/NF
   prt($0, "Avg pie:  " avg "pie")
   ++rec
   sum += avg
}
!NF
END {
   prt("\nTotal Average:", sum/rec "pie")
}' file
```

Comment: This absolutely worked and was exactly what I was looking for.
@anubhava how would you compensate if there were empty lines between the rows?
To avoid warnings such as `(FILENAME=- FNR=9) fatal: division by zero attempted`

Comment: Curious why you didn't write `avg = s / NF`

Comment: But I like the combination of OFS and column

Comment: @glennjackman: Indeed I should have used `avg.= s/NF` (have edited now) Thanks

Comment: This converts pie to pi!

Comment: Thanks @karakfa, it is fixed now.

Comment: @anubhava this also works. But for a file with empty lines it will remove the lines on output which is fine but then will also include the empty line in the division of the total average. So will give an inaccurate total average. ie. if there were 8 rows with pie but 2 extra empty lines, it will divide by 10 instead of 8

Comment: Curious is there a way to retain the empty lines on output instead of concatenating? @anubhava

Comment: to keep empty lines add `!NF` before the `END` block.

Comment: That didn't work for me @karakfa `} !NF END {` or `} !NFEND {`

Comment: OK, if you're putting on the same line, do `!NF; END...`  On a separate line you don' t need the semicolon.

Comment: @karakfa I think the problem is that column still concatenates it `column -t -s $'\t'` . Works without it but messy.

Comment: For `column` add `-e` to keep empty lines.

Comment: Perfect! It outputs nicely.

Comment: `column` command on `OSX` doesn't have `-e` option so I have changed awk command to work with `printf` only, without any `column`.

Answer (score 2):

Perl, but it really offers no advantage over anubhava's answer

```sh
perl -MList::Util=sum,max -lane '
      sub avg {sum(@_) / @_}
      push @lines, $_;
      push @avg, avg(@F);
  } END {
      $maxl = max map {length} @lines;
      printf "%-*s Avg:\n", $maxl, "Instances of Pie:";
      printf "%-*s Avg pie: %.1fpie\n", $maxl, $lines[$_] , $avg[$_]
          for 0..$#lines;
      printf "\n%-*s          %.2fpie\n", $maxl, "Total Average:", avg(@avg);
' pie.txt
```